# calculate the percentage contribution of a value in a column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below data frame

```
 item1  item2    item3    
  x      y         z    
  x1     y1        z1   
  x      y2        z2   
  x      y         z1
  x2     y         z         
  x2     y1        z2
```

i want to find the percentage contribution of each value in a column to the all value in the column(what is the contribution of x,x1,x2 in item1 same with item2 and item3)

The below must be the result data frame.

```
item1  %con_item1  item2  %con_item2  item3 %con_item3
x          50       y        50         z       33.33
x1         16.66    y1       33.33      z1      33.33
x2         33.33    y2       16.66      z2      33.33
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you were *supposed* to finish before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Use `value_counts` with `normalize` parameter set to True:

```
pd.concat([df[i].value_counts(normalize=True).reset_index() for i in df.columns], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  index     item1 index     item2 index     item3
0     x  0.500000     y  0.500000    z1  0.333333
1    x2  0.333333    y1  0.333333    z2  0.333333
2    x1  0.166667    y2  0.166667     z  0.333333
```

#### Updated answer with scaling and column naming:

```
pd.concat([df[i].value_counts(normalize=True)
                .mul(100.0)
                .rename_axis(i)
                .reset_index(name='%con_'+i)  for i in df.columns], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  item1  %con_item1 item2  %con_item2 item3  %con_item3
0     x   50.000000     y   50.000000    z1   33.333333
1    x2   33.333333    y1   33.333333    z2   33.333333
2    x1   16.666667    y2   16.666667     z   33.333333
```

Comment: @user3483203 Thank you.   Looking for a clean way to name the columns like OP wants.